# Why does 36W LED bulb not light up?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I bought a 36W (220V/50Hz/425mA/E27) [LED growlight](https://www.amazon.nl/SANSI-Led-plantenlamp-daglichtwit-kamerplanten-hydrocultuur/dp/B07T47VQX4/ref=pd_bxgy_img_2/259-5275976-7040902?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07T47VQX4&pd_rd_r=483a2e6f-6ccf-43e6-8e9a-5884892d892b&pd_rd_w=pc6Bk&pd_rd_wg=2SAin&pf_rd_p=91a9666c-600c-487c-9718-17de371da44c&pf_rd_r=PWNYS6XASNS6STFP5VNX&psc=1&refRID=PWNYS6XASNS6STFP5VNX) (well, only the lightbulb).
To make it work, I also ordered a simple [lampholder](https://www.amazon.nl/Lixada-flexibele-zwanenhals-bureaulamp-plantenbouw/dp/B07C4Y9HXK/ref=asc_df_B07C4Y9HXK/?tag=nlshogostdde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=430527493653&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10261833290095558578&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9065312&hvtargid=pla-855648307612&th=1) (AKA the other part of the lamp).

After wiring it up, the light bulb doesn't work. I have already tested the lampholder with other bulbs (both lower wattage) and they all work.

Now I turn to you guys. Is the lampholder too 'weak' for 36W, or is the LED bulb broken?

Comment: The voltage range is 90-260 vac.  It would be hard to have the wrong voltage, at that I would guess it is dead.  Since you have tried using another lamp the socket is good. Time to test amazon’s return policy in your area.

Answer (score 2):

If the lamp fits the socket, there is no problem with it being "underpowered". This appears to be a simple socket *without* ballast, just an on/off switch in series.

Two possible causes of the issue:

- The center contact of the "Edison base" E27 screw socket might not be making contact, particularly if another lamp pushed the contact down. **Unplug the socket from the mains!** Then *gently* pry up the unattached end of the center contact. Hopefully, this will fix it; please let me know if it works.

[image: E27 center contact]

- The lamp sold to you may indeed be defective. Return it for a replacement.

Comment: I agree, the flange on the lamp socket is striking the outsize housing of the LED driver. That is preventing it from screwing in enough to contact the bottom of the socket.

Comment: I have pried up the center contact, and that doesn't solve the problem. Still, thank you for answering!

Comment: I will mark correct answer if a get a replacement bulb and it works, thus confirming that the lamp was defective